# How come I'm getting an error in merge Debug Resources?

Tags: java, android

[image: Error mergeDebudResources]

I've seen a couple of similar problems, but couldn't seem to figure out how to fix the error I'm getting as I run the application.

I understand that there is probably an easy solution to this, but I would still appreciate some direction.

Comment: please share with us your code and the line that you get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here you are missing something in `activity_list_online.xml` in line no 23 tag, Check your whole code in 23 line tag eg. TextView,ImageView or whatever you have.

It will fix your problem definatly.[image: Check line no 23 in this layout]